# I can't get DRF-Spectactular to generate OpenApiParameter valuesin Swagger for functions, only classes

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

Currently I'm working on a django project and I have an `api_views.py` file with the following view function:

```py
@api_view(["GET"])
@extend_schema(
    parameters=[
        OpenApiParameter(
            name="jurisdiction", description="City for the query", required=True, type=str, default="Boston"
        ),
    ],
    description='More descriptive text',
    responses={200: OpenApiTypes.OBJECT},  # Define your response schema
)
def distinct_address_autocomplete(request: Request):
    jurisdiction = request.GET.get("jurisdiction", "Boston")

    # Get distinct addresses for the city
    addresses = get_distinct_addresses(jurisdiction)

    # Filter addresses based on user's query
    filtered_addresses = addresses  # Implement your filtering logic

    return Response(filtered_addresses)
```

I've got it all set up correctly in all the `settings.py` and `urls.py` because it shows up in swagger, but incorrectly. The `OpenApiParameter` doesn't show up at all, it looks like this:

[image: screenshot of swagger]

But when I refactor this as a class like so:

```py
class DistinctAddressAutocompleteView(APIView):
    @extend_schema(
        parameters=[
            OpenApiParameter(
                name="jurisdiction", description="City for the query", required=True, type=str, default="Boston"
            ),
        ],
        description='More descriptive text',
        responses={200: OpenApiTypes.OBJECT},  # Define your response schema
    )
    def get(self, request: Request):
        jurisdiction = request.GET.get("jurisdiction", "Boston")

        # Get distinct addresses for the city
        addresses = get_distinct_addresses(jurisdiction)

        # Filter addresses based on user's query
        filtered_addresses = addresses  # Implement your filtering logic

        return Response(filtered_addresses)
```

The parameter shows up!

[image: Class API view working as intended]

What am I doing wrong on the function view? As best I can tell, I've set it up correctly, I've checked the DRF-Spec docs and I'm stumped at this point.